# Get the date only

Tags: 7, datetime

I found out that `print render($content['created']);` displays the date the node was created. But it shows other info as well such as the author's name. Is there a way so only the date comes out? And can that date be given a different format?

Comment: I got it! It was something else entirely: `print format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'F j, Y')`. Thanks to http://drupal.org/node/71106.

Comment: It's been established that it is perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your question so that people can upvote it and after other answers are submitted, or not, for you to check it to let other people know there does exist a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use `<?php print $date?>` in the node.tpl.php file. In Drupal 7 the markup is wrapped in lovely RDF for future SEO happiness.

Comment: How can I remove hour and weekday name from $date?